# Can't upload file to oboom.com API

Tags: php, curl

I try to upload a file via oboom.com API (https://www.oboom.com/api/1/ul)

```
$ch2 = curl_init("http://upload.oboom.com/1/ul?token=My API Key&parent=1");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1');
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_REFERER, '');
$arr = array('file' => new CURLFile ("test.txt"));
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $arr); 
$output = curl_exec($ch2);      
curl_close($ch2);
echo $output;
```

I get: `[404,"item",["1"]]`

Please help me to correct that code example! Thanks!

Comment: Did you use an empty token? I suppose you should get a token via first request, and only after that send an upload request.

Comment: No I use my Api-Key as token how it is written in the API!

Comment: Have you created folder "1" before?

Comment: this is the root folder!

Comment: as far as I understand, `parent` is a folder ID in which you want to upload your file. But there is no folder there with ID=1, therefore you have an 404 error.

Comment: General notes

"The filesystem has two different objects. Files and folders. Also it has two special root items.
The root has the ID 1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to get token param from login session response,

save this file to generate password hash:
[PasswordStorage.php](https://github.com/defuse/password-hashing/blob/ef0f34764f8a9a584c69b9c235c847942541ea1e/PasswordStorage.php)

```
function login($email, $pass)
{
    $mysalt     = strrev($pass);
    $hash       = PasswordStorage::pbkdf2('sha1', $pass, $mysalt, 1000, 16);

    $ch2 = curl_init("https://www.oboom.com/1/login?auth=$email&pass=$hash");
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1');
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_REFERER, '');
    $output = curl_exec($ch2);
    curl_close($ch2);
    return json_decode($output);
}

function upload($token, $file)
{
    $ch2 = curl_init("http://upload.oboom.com/1/ul?token=$token&parent=1");
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1');
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_REFERER, '');
    $arr = array('file' => new CURLFile ($file));
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $arr); 
    $output = curl_exec($ch2);      
    curl_close($ch2);
    return json_decode($output);
}


$login  = login('youremail@email.com', 'yourPassword');
$token  = $login[1]->session;

$upload = upload($token, 'test.txt');
var_dump($upload);
```

for using looping upload, you can save token as file and read the token if exist to avoid logging in repeatedly.

Comment: I get this error: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'PasswordStorage'

Comment: im missing including the file, save this to same folder: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/defuse/password-hashing/master/PasswordStorage.php